# Heroku pipeline - which app is code linked to

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-pipelines

I have been deploying to a single app on heroku. I have decided to create a pipeline and I set this app as the production app. I created a new app for staging.

Which app should the local code be linked to and pushed to with git push heroku master? Is it the staging app or the production app?

Do I need to run a command to let my local repo know that I want it sent to the staging app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to run a command to let my local repo know that I want it sent to the staging app?

See "[Heroku: Managing Multiple Environments for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)"

The command would be:

```
git config heroku.remote staging
```

> Once this is set up, all `heroku` commands will default to the `staging` app.
> To run a command on the production app, simply use the `--remote production` option.

The [OP Joshua Foxworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087990/joshua-foxworth) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343126/heroku-pipeline-which-app-is-code-linked-to/49343440#comment85688169_49343440):

> Turns out that even after running the config command, I still had to specify the staging app.
>
> ```
> git config heroku.remote staging
> ```
>
> Then:
>
> ```
> git push staging master
> ```

Comment: so, I can enter git push heroku master and it will go to the staging app once I have entered this?

Comment: Whoops. Tried this ... even with setting the git remote to the staging app, it still deployed to the production app

Comment: Turns out that even after running the config command, I still had to specify the staging app. ...
git config heroku.remote staging ... then ... 
 git push staging master

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth Great! I have included your comment in the answer for making that step more visible.